# How to dynamically render JSX component X times?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

Consider a simple example of the render function of a React component:

```
render () {
  const rowLimit = this.props.rowLimit ? this.props.rowLimit : 5
  return (
    <tbody>
      {row()}
      {row()}
      {row()}
      {row()}
      {row()}
    </tbody>
  )
}
```

Currently `rowLimit` is useless.. but I would like to use that number to determine how many `{rows()}`s are rendered. Is there a clean way to do this?

Using a `for (let i = 0; i < rowLimit; i++)` loop feels clunky... I will award style points for a better solution

Note: `row()` returns a JSX element

Comment: Check out [this tut](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [Array#from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) to convert limit to an array of rows:

```js
class Tbody extends React.Component {
  render () {
    const { rowLimit = 5 } = this.props; // destructure with defaults instead of trinary
    
    return (
      <tbody>
      {
        Array.from({ length: rowLimit }, (_, k) => (
          <tr key={k}>
            <td>{k}</td>
          </tr>
        ))
      }
      </tbody>
    )
  }  
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <table>
    <Tbody />
  </table>,
  demo
);
```

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Answer (score 4):

I believe something like this will work for you:

```
render () {
  const rowLimit = this.props.rowLimit ? this.props.rowLimit : 5;
  let rows = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < rowLimit; i++) {
    rows.push(<Row key={Math.floor(Date.now() + i)} />);
  }

  return (
    <tbody>
      { rows }
    </tbody>
  )
}
```

where Row is your row component that you can add props to if you wish.

Comment: This does not work, you cannot render an array (`rows`) in JSX  with `{rows}`

Comment: it works just fine, and yes you can render an array as { rows }, as long as what is inside is html/jsx code. Of course, above you will have to change rows.push(<Row />) to the name of your component, or some other jsx/html. Take a look at my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/smlacerda5/bxhp72zp/

Answer (score 3):

You can do this 

`{ [...Array(rowLimit).keys()].map(() => row()) }`

with lodash even create the array with `_.range()`, but in my opinion it doesn't worth it, stevelacerda7 solution is neat enough.

Answer (score 0):

It's really useful when you need a placeholder kind of data like **React** Shimmer Element **(ShimmerElementsGroup)** in **JSX.Element** based **components** and need to control the length or other attributes.

Sample code:

> ```
> import { ShimmerElementsGroup, ShimmerElementType } from "@fluentui/react";
> const wrapperStyle = { display: 'flex' };
> export const getShimmerData = (rowCount : number): JSX.Element => {
>     let rows = [];
>     for (let i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
>         rows.push(
>             <div style={wrapperStyle}>
>                 <ShimmerElementsGroup
>                     width={'90px'}
>                     shimmerElements={[
>                         { type: ShimmerElementType.line, height: 80, width: 80 },
>                         { type: ShimmerElementType.gap, width: 10, height: 80 },
>                     ]}
>                 />
>                 <div style={{ display: 'flex', flexWrap: 'wrap', width: '100%' }}>
>                     <ShimmerElementsGroup
>                         shimmerElements={[
>                             { type: ShimmerElementType.circle, height: 40 },
>                             { type: ShimmerElementType.gap, width: 10, height: 40 },
>                         ]}
>                     />
>                     <ShimmerElementsGroup
>                         flexWrap
>                         width={'calc(100% - 50px)'}
>                         shimmerElements={[
>                             { type: ShimmerElementType.line, width: '90%', height: 10 },
>                             { type: ShimmerElementType.gap, width: '10%', height: 20 },
>                             { type: ShimmerElementType.line, width: '100%', height: 10 },
>                         ]}
>                     />
>                     <ShimmerElementsGroup
>                         flexWrap
>                         width={'100%'}
>                         shimmerElements={[
>                             { type: ShimmerElementType.line, width: '80%', height: 10, verticalAlign: 'bottom' },
>                             { type: ShimmerElementType.gap, width: '20%', height: 20 },
>                             { type: ShimmerElementType.line, width: '40%', height: 10, verticalAlign: 'bottom' },
>                             { type: ShimmerElementType.gap, width: '2%', height: 20 },
>                             { type: ShimmerElementType.line, width: '58%', height: 10, verticalAlign: 'bottom' },
>                         ]}
>                     />
>                 </div>
>             </div>
>         );
>     }
>     return (
>         <div>
>           { rows }
>         </div>
>       )
> };
>
> export default getShimmerData
> ```