# How to store components in an array and render them when I need in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, array.prototype.map

I want to render x numbers times a specific component according to what the user chooses.

I wrote this function:

```
const generateShiftsForm = (totalWeeks) => {
        const shiftWeeks = 1;
        const shiftList = [];
        for (let i = shiftWeeks; i === totalWeeks; i++) {
          shiftList.push(<ShiftForm totalMinutes={totalMinutes} setTotalMinutes={setTotalMinutes}/>);
        }
        return shiftList;
      };
```

But when I call it inside the render function it doesn't generate anything unless the `totalWeeks` is 1.

```
  {generateShiftsForm(shiftNumber).map((form) => (form))}
```

Why is it like this? I didn't get it, can someone explain it to me?

Comment: `i === totalWeeks` should be `i <= totalWeeks`

Comment: Your loop condition isn't correct and only ever true when the starting and ending value are the same, i.e. both 1, or both 2, etc. Don't store react components in state, it's a sure-fire way to get stale state/prop enclosures. You should store just the data and render the UI from it. In your render use something like `[...Array(totalWeeks).keys()].map(i => <ShiftForm key={i} tota......`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46964332/how-to-dynamically-render-jsx-component-x-times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like there is a typo in the for loop condition - `i === totalWeeks`, that's why the for loop is being run only once and only if `totalWeeks` equals 1. Try replacing the for loop you have with the following:

```
for (let i = shiftWeeks; i <= totalWeeks; i++) {...}
```